# NSFetchedResultsController issue: index 1 beyond bounds, managing custom table view cells

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am stumped with implementing the NSFetchedResultsController as I keep getting errors. I am trying to connect Core Data with the UITableView, and I am not getting to the next step by having UITableView draw out the correct number of rows according to the number of records from Core Data. I get this error message:

```
*** Terminating app
due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** 
[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Here's my code below:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CustomerProfileViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!

    var itemList: [NSManagedObject] = [] // I hope to have the fetch results controller manage this object

    // The data model contains one entity "Item" with one attribute "name"

    lazy var fetchResultsControllerItem: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> = {

        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

        // Initialize Fetch Results Controller
        let fetchResultsControllerItem = 
            NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.managedContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultsControllerItem.delegate = self
        return fetchResultsControllerItem
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            try fetchResultsControllerItem.performFetch()
            print("Fetch worked! ")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "SummaryCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SummaryCell")
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "ListingsCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListingsCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2 // Corresponds to the custom table view cells as Nib files
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "SUMMARY"
        } else if section == 1 {
            return "ITEM LISTINGS"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {

/* Adding the "guard let sections" to the "return
sectionInfo.numberOfObject" below causes an error: *** Terminating app
due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** 
[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' */
enter code here
            guard let sections = fetchResultsControllerItem.sections else {
                return 0
            }
            let sectionInfo = sections[section]
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects

        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell
            cell.totalNumberOfItems?.text = "\(itemList.count)"
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListingsCell", for: indexPath) as! ListingsCell
            let listItem = fetchResultsControllerItem.object(at: indexPath)
            cell.itemName?.text = listItem.name
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Below displays the file containing the CoreDataStack implementation:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {

    private let modelName: String

    init(modelName: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
    }

    lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.storeContainer.viewContext
    }()

    private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext() {
        guard managedContext.hasChanges else { return }

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

I did use Liya to confirm that there are Items with names on record after examining the sqlite file. To whomever having any tips or ideas, I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in the FetchedResultsController’s view if the world, there is only one section: section 0.  But your tableView has two sections, and you want the FRC to provide the data for section 1.  So you need to remap the FRC indexPaths to the correct section in the table view, in the tableView datasource methods.  So in `numberOfRowsInSection`, your code is currently asking the FRC for the number of objects in section 1, and the FRC throws the error because, as far as it is concerned, there is no section 1.  Just replace:

```
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
```

with:

```
        let sectionInfo = sections[0]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
```

in that method.  Then in `cellForRowAt`, replace this:

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListingsCell", for: indexPath) as! ListingsCell
        let listItem = fetchResultsControllerItem.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.itemName?.text = listItem.name
        return cell
```

with this:

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListingsCell", for: indexPath) as! ListingsCell
        let listItem = fetchResultsControllerItem.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]
        cell.itemName?.text = listItem.name
        return cell
```

(This uses the `fetchedObjects` property of the FRC to avoid using the wrong section in the indexPath in `object(at:)`).

Comment: Thanks very much for the corrections @pbasdf! The codes worked: the numberOfObjects provide the numberOfRowsInSection and the listItem.name from FRC provide data for cell.itemName.

Comment: However, the tableView contains added data after relaunching the app. I did add the boilerplate codes for the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate -> controllerWIllChangeContent, controller(_ controller:didChange anObject:at indexPath:for type:new IndexPath:), controller(_ controller:didChange sectionInfo:atSectionIntex sectionIndex:for type:), and controllerDidChangeContent. FRC appears to be adding to section 0 and not 1: "An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0."

Comment: I should have said: in the FRC delegate methods, you need to do the reverse mapping: the FRC will indicate that a new object has been added in section 0, but you need to add the corresponding row to section 1 of the tableView.  Something like `let tvIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 1)`

Comment: I'll look into that functionality. Thanks for your help @pbasdf.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like if I declared let mapIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 1), the insertion of new data works like a charm. But deletion using self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with .fade) caused this error: "error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list." I tried replacing the at: argument with [mapIndexPath as IndexPath] like I did for the insert case, and still problematic.